# How can I add the string text to the method that get string[]?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this string that contain text inside:

```
readableRss = RssReader.covertRss("http://rotter.net/rss/rotternews.xml");
```

readbleRss is a string variable.

Then I have this code:

```
SetupText(new string[] { "Hello everyone this is the weather for today", "Text2", "hello world this is a test for long text what do you think", "Text 4 -> 4", "Text Nr. 5" });
SetupColors(new Color[] { Color.Blue, Color.Lime, Color.Maroon, Color.FromArgb(255, 71, 71, 255), Color.BurlyWood });

private void SetupColors(Color[] colors)
{
      if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 0 && colors.Length > 0)
             this.newsFeed1.TextColor[0] = colors[0];
      if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 1 && colors.Length > 1)
             this.newsFeed1.TextColor[1] = colors[1];
      if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 2 && colors.Length > 2)
             this.newsFeed1.TextColor[2] = colors[2];
      if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 3 && colors.Length > 3)
             this.newsFeed1.TextColor[3] = colors[3];
      if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 4 && colors.Length > 4)
             this.newsFeed1.TextColor[4] = colors[4];
}

private void SetupText(string[] textToDisplay)
    {
         if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 0 && textToDisplay.Length > 0)
              this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[0] = textToDisplay[0];
          if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 1 && textToDisplay.Length > 1)
              this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[1] = textToDisplay[1];
          if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 2 && textToDisplay.Length > 2)
              this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[2] = textToDisplay[2];
          if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 3 && textToDisplay.Length > 3)
              this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[3] = textToDisplay[3];
          if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 4 && textToDisplay.Length > 4)
              this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[4] = textToDisplay[4];
    }
```

What I want is that instead adding to the news feeder the text from SetupText(new string[] { 
To add the text from readableRss

My program making the text to move scroll in animation from down to up like a news feeder.

The website is rss feed site.
So I want each line from the rss to be scrolled with my code.

This is en example of how the format looks like in the variable readbleRss:

```
אם הרב אלקנה אליאסי נרצח ברקע לאומני?
Mon, 27 Jan 2014 10:27:40 +0200

ביל גייטס הובס תוך דקה ע''י צעיר בן 23 במשחק שחמט
Mon, 27 Jan 2014 10:25:30 +0200

מי יציל את המוסד לביטוח לאומי? - החל מ2042 לא יישאר כסף לקצבאות
Mon, 27 Jan 2014 10:25:03 +0200
```

EDIT**

This is what i tried now but its not working i dont see any text when running the program:

```
readableRss = RssReader.covertRss("http://rotter.net/rss/rotternews.xml");
            for (int i = 0; i < readableRss.Length; i++)
            {
                this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed = new string[i];
                string t = Convert.ToString(readableRss[i]);
                SetupText(new string[] { t });
            }
            this.newsFeed1.TextColor = new Color[1];
            SetupColors(new Color[] { Color.Blue });
```

Comment: This might be relevant btw: [MSDN - for loop (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx).  :)

Comment: How does the string returned by `RssReader.convertRss()` looks like? Consider to split it or make a method to accept `string` (which will put it into `random` or `first` or `next` scrolling fields, depends on what you want).

Comment: Updated my question with what i tried now so far but its not working.

Comment: `this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed = new string[i];` - There's one problem.  EVerytime you go through an iteration of the loop, you're assigning a new string array to `NewsTextFeed`.  I don't think you want to do that - try initializing the string array to the size `readableRss` outside the loop.  Then call `SetupText` once the loop is done.

Comment: Doing readableRss.Length is not good in the FOR loop. I need somehow to loop over the number of lines in readableRss. In my question i added the content example of the variable readableRss each text line with the date and time is like one line should be in the control moving up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split your string as per lines you can use this

```
string[] lines = Regex.Split(readableRss, "\r\n");
```

Of course you need to include the corresponding namespace.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Hope this helps.